# .bashrc: Set tabs to show program name

Tags: bash, terminal, iterm2

Trying to create .bashrc function to rename tab titles to reflect the program name when in nvim.

So far I have:

```
function title() { echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD##*/}\007"; }
PROMPT_COMMAND=title
```

However this only shows my directory, not the file name.

I have also tried:

```
function tab_title {
  if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    title=${PWD##*/}
  else
    title=$1
  fi
  echo -n -e "\033]0;$title\007"
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=tab_title
```

However, this also only displays the current working directory, not the file name. I am unsure why.

Comment: From Vim (and Neovim) documentation: `When starting Vim "vim -p filename ..." opens each file argument in a separate tab page (up to 'tabpagemax').`

Comment: @Sergio I think they want the terminal tab to show the name of the file. Nothing to do with vim tabs.

Comment: Sorry, yes, for clarity I need this on the bash level, not vim. Vim was just an example of the main way I will use this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions to this (see https://superuser.com/questions/175799/).  This one requires bash 4.4 or newer.  Command history should be enabled (`set -o history`), and `PROMPT_COMMAND` unset.

```
PS0='\[\e]0;$(fc -lnr -0)\007\\'
```

PS0 is printed just before command is executed, but after it has been entered into history.